# Clip {ggdist} ccdf-barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a complementary cumulative distribution function barplot with {ggdist}. When I export the plot to svg (or other vector representation), I notice that there is a zero-width stripe protruding from the polygon (see attached image). I rather not have this protruding stripe.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdist)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10),
  y = c(rnorm(20, mean = rep(c(5, 7), each = 10)))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  stat_ccdfinterval(geom = "slab") +
  lims(y = c(0, NA))

ggsave("test.svg", plot = p, device = svglite::svglite)
```

The code above results in an svg file below, wherein I've highlighted the outline of the polygon with the stripe.

[image]

I'd like to get rid of that zero-width stripe. I tried setting the relevant aesthetic to `NA` at these points, but that also deletes one of the corners that is not part of the stripe.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  stat_ccdfinterval(
    geom = "slab", 
    aes(thickness = after_stat(ifelse(f == 0, NA, f)))
  ) +
  lims(y = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hmmm... Currently not a great solution to this. You can set `expand = FALSE` to get rid of it but it will also remove the extension of the bottom of the slabs down to the baseline. Can I ask why you need it gone?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the personal response! In addition: thanks for setting up and maintaining the package! It is absolutely no other reason than I'm preparing a figure using {ggdist} for publication and I'd like to nail down the figure as truthfully as I can (I apologise for the nitpicking!). I'm now adding a clipping mask in an editor (illustrator) to constrain the protrusion to the data range, but it'd be more ideal for reproducibility purposes to do this programmatically.

Comment: Yeah, this makes me think there's a better way to handle NAs in the thickness aesthetic that would support this case and others more easily. I wonder if you could open an issue about this on https://github.com/mjskay/ggdist/issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution specific to this problem, but it might pan out differently if the orientation is horizontal or the cdf instead of the ccdf is used. In brief, we're still setting 0-thickness datapoints to `NA`, but we now do this only where the `y` aesthetic exceeds the groupwise maximum.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdist)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10),
  y = c(rnorm(20, mean = rep(c(5, 7), each = 10)))
)

helper <- function(f, y, group) {
  split(f, group) <- Map(
    function(value, y) {
      f <- value
      max_y <- max(y[f != 0])
      f[f == 0 & y > max_y] <- NA
      f
    },
    value = split(f, group),
    y     = split(y, group)
  )
  f
}

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  stat_ccdfinterval(
    geom = "slab", 
    aes(thickness = after_stat(helper(f, y, group)))
  ) +
  lims(y = c(0, NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>